# CultureInfo for Latin language

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, lcid

I develop an app for working with multi-language resources.
In database, when I need colomn with language identifier, I use language LCID.
Now I need to add new language - Latin. It's LCID - 1142. But when I try to create new CultureInfo(1142) - exception thrown.
Is there any way to solve this problem? Somehow add Latin language to CultureInfo available languages.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I'm curious what sort of app you're writing that's going to be used by people who only speak a dead language.

Comment: Code page 1142 is an EBCDIC code page used in Denmark and Norway.  It is as dead as those Italians.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem. I wrote an add-in for Word which allows to insert Bible quotes from different Bible versions, among which there are Latin versions of the Bible. When my add-in tries to display the localized name of the Latin language, it comes to a hault on Windows 7 systems, it works however on Windows 10 systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that is possible. Latin is not supported as a culture.

The .NET Framework has specific functionality for [creating custom cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx), but you don't get to decide the LCID. The LCID is always `0x1000` for a custom culture.

> For replacement cultures the culture identifier is mapped to the corresponding National Language Support (NLS) locale identifier. *For user-defined custom cultures, the value of this property is always hexadecimal 0x1000.*
>
> [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.lcid.aspx)

You may be better off storing the name of the culture in the database, instead of the LCID. This would allow you to load custom cultures since they are always loaded by name. Once that is done, you can proceed to create your own culture.